# How to solve 6 high severity vulnerabilities right after creating react app while installing icons

Tags: reactjs, npm

the only thing done before this is `npx create-react-app .`

```
npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled

added 34 packages, and audited 1478 packages in 2m

  run `npm fund` for details

6 high severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.
```

I tried `npm audit fix --force` but it only makes it worse
also tried `npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled --force` but this doesn't work neither

Comment: I guess you'll have to run `npm audit` for more details and work out what to do with each problem individually. Once you know what the problems are - I'd guess dependencies that need updating - you can try reaching out to the separate projects that you included to see if they can release new versions that address the problems, and/or submit MRs to them to fix the problems too. Either that or determine whether the reported issues are relevant to how you're using the code, and ignore them if not.

Comment: nth-check  <2.0.1
Severity: high
Inefficient Regular Expression Complexity in nth-check - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-rp65-9cf3-cjxr
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install react-scripts@2.1.3, which is a breaking change
node_modules/svgo/node_modules/nth-check
  css-select  <=3.1.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of nth-check
  node_modules/svgo/node_modules/css-select
    svgo  1.0.0 - 1.3.2
    Depends on vulnerable versions of css-select
    node_modules/svgo

Comment: @svgr/plugin-svgo  <=5.5.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of svgo
      node_modules/@svgr/plugin-svgo
        @svgr/webpack  4.0.0 - 5.5.0
        Depends on vulnerable versions of @svgr/plugin-svgo
        node_modules/@svgr/webpack
          react-scripts  >=2.1.4
          Depends on vulnerable versions of @svgr/webpack
          node_modules/react-scripts

6 high severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Comment: https://overreacted.io/npm-audit-broken-by-design/